# python: save strings and numbers to a txt file

Tags: python

I want to print some strings and numerical values to a txt file. The output is something like:

```
Accuracy: 0.98
Loss: 0.10
```

My codes are follows:

```
output_file = open('filepath','w')
output_file.write('Accuracy:\n',0.98)
output_file.write('Loss:\n',0.10)
output_file.close()
```

But they won't work due to the write function "TypeError: function takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)"

Comment: Please take a look at [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#format).

Answer (score 5):

While other answers are correct, its better to open the `file` using `with`:

```
with open('file', 'w') as output_file:
    output_file.write('foo')
    output_file.write('bar')
```

this way the `file` will auto close when the writing finishes.

Answer (score 1):

You can not pass multiple strings to the write function. Try casting the floats to strings and concatinating:

```
output_file = open('filepath','w')
output_file.write('Accuracy:\n'+str(0.98))
output_file.write('Loss:\n'+str(0.10))

output_file.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

I was wrong! I forgot to add % identifier to recognize the numbers. The codes should be:

```
output_file = open('filepath.txt','w')
output_file.write('Accuracy: %1.2f\n' % (0.98,))
output_file.write('Loss: %1.2f\n' %  (0.10,))
output_file.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way to write code for text output in Python is to use the `print` function. (It's a function in Python 3, but was a statement in Python 2.)

```
print('Accuracy:', 0.98, file=output_file)
print('Loss:', 0.10, file=output_file)
```

The Python 2 equivalent is:

```
print >>output_file, 'Accuracy:', 0.98
print >>output_file, 'Loss:', 0.10
```

You still have the same open/close requirements.  The advantage is that everything you know about writing text to the standard output device works with writing to text files.

One extra feature is that if the output_file value is None, either version will write to the standard output stream (the console/terminal if not redirected) so you can very simply define functions that will write to a file or the console, such as:

```
def show_stats(accuracy, loss, file=None):
'''display accuracy and loss on console, or specified file'''
    print('Accuracy:', accuracy, file=file)
    print('Loss:', loss, file=file)
```

Then, call that with either or both of:

```
show_stats(0.98, 0.10) # output to stdout
show_stats(0.98, 0.10, file=output_file) # output to text file
```